# Magento 2 : Is there a file system map for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, code

Ultimately I want to add **code snippets** to some or all pages on my **website**, specifically, the code is the **Facebook pixel** code is the `google` tag manager code.

I've found a number of similar questions and they are usually well answered, but where I get lost is the files to use.

I've seen answers that say to put the "**reference**" block of code in XML files but they can be named from `view.xml`, `default.xml`, `theme.xml`, `page.xml` etc. And then when I search the Magento file system, I often get many many results.

The question is which file do I use?